# Python, pytesseract not recognizing image

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have this code simple code

Path to exe is right, path to screenshot is right there is an image

[image: screenshot.jpg]

Why it can't recognize text, even if it's not something unreadable

I tried using ImageEnhance, threshold and converting to grayscale
Also I tried with .png format, it still doesn't work
Why does it happening?

```
import pytesseract as pt
from PIL import Image

pt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'D:\\tesseract\\tesseract.exe'

def extract_text_from_image(image_path):

    img = Image.open(image_path)

    text = pt.image_to_string(img)
    
    return text

image_path = 'D:\\script\\materials\\screenshot.jpg'
text = extract_text_from_image(image_path)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to read the text from your image, by passing the page segmentation mode 6 to the "image_to_string"-methode.

```
pt.image_to_string(img, config="--psm 6")
```

You can find out more about the different segmentation modes and what they do here:
https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/